# Openerp module output not generated properly

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

Here is my code:

```
import product_specification
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
'name': "Product Specification",
'version': "1.0",
'author': "iologic",
'category': "Tools",
'depends': ['product'],
'data': ['product_specification.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
```

}

product_specification.py

```
    from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class product_specification(osv.osv):

  _inherit = "product.product"
  _name = "product.specification"

  _columns = {
    'prototype': fields.char('Prototype#', size=20),
    'style': fields.char('Style#', size=20),
    'customer': fields.char('Customer', size=20),
    'body_type': fields.char('Body Type', size=20),
    'program_brand': fields.char('Program/Brand', size=20),
    'color_asstmnt': fields.char('Color Asstmnt', size=200),
    'size_info': fields.integer('Size Info', size=20),
    'description': fields.char('Description', size=500),
    'designer': fields.char('Designer', size=20),
    'factory': fields.char('factory', size=20),
    'pcs_hanger': fields.integer('Pcs/Hanger', size=20),
    'developed_sold': fields.char('Developed/Sold', size=20),

  }


product_specification()
```

product_specification.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_specification_product">
    <field name="name">product.specification</field>
    <field name="model">product.specification</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="Create Product Specification" version="7.0">
        <field name="prototype">prototype</field>
        <field name="style">style</field>
        <field name="customer">customer</field>
        <field name="body_type">body type</field>
        <field name="program_brand">program brand</field>
        <field name="color_asstmnt">color Asstment</field>
        <field name="size_info">size info</field>
        <field name="description">description</field>
        <field name="designer">designer</field>
        <field name="factory">factory</field>
        <field name="pcs_hanger">pcs hanger</field>
        <field name="developed_sold">developed sold</field>
       </form>
    </field>
</record>
<record id="product_specification_product_act_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Product Specification</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.specification</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_specification_product"/>
</record>
<menuitem id="menu_product_specification" name="Product Specification" action="product_specification_product_act_window"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Here is the output :

[image: Screen capture for output view]

No, fields tag / name / id. How to define that & solve this problem.

I also study this link:

http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_03.html

But still can't fix that. More over I am not write any tree view code for my this module. So, when I go to tree view it's showing some warning error too. Need to understand the difference of views & solve existing bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. use group or label. update your view.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_specification_product">
<field name="name">product.specification</field>
<field name="model">product.specification</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">   
  <form string="Create Product Specification" version="7.0">
    <group>
    <field name="prototype"/>
    <field name="style"/>
    <field name="customer"/>
    <field name="body_type"/>
    <field name="program_brand"/>
    <field name="color_asstmnt"/>
    <field name="size_info"/>
    <field name="description"/>
    <field name="designer"/>
    <field name="factory"/>
    <field name="pcs_hanger"/>
    <field name="developed_sold"/>
    </group>
   </form>
</field>
</record>
```

and don't forget to update your module after doing this changes.

Comment: not possible.this must have worked. may i know how do you update your module.?

Comment: Put that file on addons folder module file & then Go to setting -> Apply Scheduled Upgrades -> Update

Comment: I was try to uninstall it. But is showing this error -> Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: ir.model.constraint - ir.model.constraint]

Comment: you are doing wrong. Go to setting -> installed modules -> now search you module name in filter. click on your module, you will see form view showing your modules details. there would be button named "upgrade". click on that. it will update changes then check again

Comment: Create a new VM & database. Try it, showing a tag error, solve it & now it's running.

Comment: But when i input data & try to save it showing this following error.

Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: name - name]

Comment: okey :). sorry I have seen your comments now. tell me if any other issue occurs.